# Is it worth it to check LinkedHashSet.contains(...) before adding?

Tags: java, performance, linkedhashset

I'm using a `LinkedHashSet` to implement a set ordered by entry. If a duplicate element is added, it should go at the end and the entry already in the set should be removed.

I'm debating whether it's worth it to check `set.contains(entry)` before I call `set.remove(entry)`? Essentially does checking `contains()` each time offer any time/space benefit over just blindly calling `remove()` each time?

```java
Set<Integer> set = new LinkedHashSet<>();

// The below
set.remove(entry);
set.add(entry);

// Versus the below
if (set.contains(entry)) {
  set.remove(entry);
}
set.add(entry);
```

Comment: No its not worth to check, brings in check-then-act problems alongwith it

Comment: @NitinDandriyal it depends if the `Set` may be reused in several threads or not.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Changing comment to - No its not worth to check as its redundant, also brings in check-then-act problems along with it in case of when multiple threads access the set.

Comment: For concurrency, you can always use `Collections.synchronizedSet(set);` to get a thread safe set from an existing one.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza It is never worthwhile to check, and, if there are multiple threads, checking will make it *worse,* by introducing timing-window errors. `Set.remove()` already has to check, obviously, and it even returns a `boolean` telling you whether it was there or not.

Comment: I would *guess*  that: if `contains` is called, the element must be searched once; when then `remove` is called, the element must be searched a second time; and when `add` is called, it must be searched a third time. (sure the `Hash` part *helps* a bit - no full scan needed)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend against calling both contains and remove. Both calls have to search through the chains to find the element, and `contains` does this no faster than `remove`. So you are potentially doubling your required time for a call each time.

You can browse through the code for [`contains`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/HashSet.java#HashSet.contains%28java.lang.Object%29) and [`remove`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/HashSet.java#HashSet.remove%28java.lang.Object%29) yourself.

You'll find that both end up possibly iterating through the hash chains at some point (`remove` in HashMap's [`removeNode`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/HashMap.java#HashMap.removeNode%28int%2Cjava.lang.Object%2Cjava.lang.Object%2Cboolean%2Cboolean%29) and `contains` in HashMap's [`getNode`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/HashMap.java#HashMap.removeNode%28int%2Cjava.lang.Object%2Cjava.lang.Object%2Cboolean%2Cboolean%29)), which could be a performance hit if your set is under heavy load.

If your set isn't under heavy load, then it still probably isn't worth it, but doesn't matter so much since in a sparse hash chains set the expected lookup/remove is O(1) (i.e. will be just as fast regardless of whether you have 5 elements or 5000 in it).

Answer (score 1):

`LinkedHashSet` uses `HashMap` behind the scenes `remove(Object)` will remove the `Object` only if it `contains` the Object hence its unnecessary and will increase time complexity in case Object exists in set.

Comment: `LinkedHashSet` is not thread safe so should not be used for multithreaded access if you're modifying it in the first place.

Comment: @Raniz That doesn't mean that you can not use `LinkedHashSet` while multiple threads are supposed to use it

Comment: Only if you *never* modify it. Calling `add` from multiple threads simultaneously is bound to mess up the internal state of the underlying `HashMap` eventually.

Comment: exactly that's why synchronization techniques are useful, even for modifying. Have you ever built a simple cache using `LinkeedHashSet` if yes you'll understand

Comment: But if you're already synchronising on your object you won't have any "check-then-act" issues  - unless you do them in separate synchronised blocks of course which would just be outright stupid.

Comment: @Raniz If by synchronizing on object you mean synchronizing on `this`, its almost never a good idea, exposes to client side locking, and how are synchronized blocks stupid(how do you even make such perceptions)?

Comment: I did not advocate any synchronisation method at all, especially not on `this` - you're the one who brought up synchronisation. I also said that *separate synchronised blocks* - as in: gain exclusive access; check; leave exclusive access; gain exclusive access again; modify; leave exclusive access; - were stupid. Read my comment again.

Comment: Vague discussion without any direction, let's close this here. Editing my  answer to remove multi-threaded part, anyways doesn't contribute to answer much.

Answer (score 0):

Java 21 added the [`addLast`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/SequencedCollection.html#addLast(E)) method to `LinkedHashSet`, which will move the element to the end of the set if it is not already present.

> Adds an element as the last element of this collection (optional operation). After this operation completes normally, the given element will be a member of this collection, and it will be the last element in encounter order.

Using this method instead of `add` solves the stated requirement without having to also call `remove`.

```java
Set<Integer> set = new LinkedHashSet<>();

set.addLast(entry);
```